# Mutex Unlock using add

Tags: mutex

While checking Mutex unlock codes around, I found some that add 1 into the mutex variable instead of setting it to "1" directly. Is there any pros/cons of this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about the pros/cons of using a mutex vs semaphore?

Comment: ...or do you just want to know why you might increment a mutex value vs setting a value to "1" (if the language gave you that option)?

Comment: No. I know they are totally different. What I mean is if I look at some low level Assembly for a Mutex, I find some implementations for "Unlock" doing "add 1,lockregisterhere" instead of saying something like "movi 1,lockregisterhere".. so what are possible pros/cons for this on a multi-core machine if it is used in a multi-threaded application? Say something as in Barriers for the threads

Comment: Yes, I just want to know the pros/cons of incrementing the value vs. setting it to "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if it is possible that you are refereeing to the difference between [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) and [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) resource access control.

---

**Edit**

That's all about CPU cycles needed for those two OPs. To my knowledge `add` uses less CPU cycles than `mov`. But then again it is very arch-dependent and questionable. Also, bear in mind that assemblers choice of how to encode a higher-level language instruction is very dependent on the surrounding instructions

Comment: No. I know what both mean. Please see my comments on my question for a clarification of what I mean.

Comment: Yup, I saw that later on. I guess it depends on the CPU architecture - some run ADD pretty fast because of the flag-setting dependecies and such while INC takes less space... what CPU did you test it on?

Comment: The Intel manual for the newer CPU series (which I guess you have) says: "Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule - INC/DEC instructions should be replaced with ADD/SUB, because ADD/SUB overwrite all flags, whereas INC/DEC instructions do not, therefore creating false dependencies on earlier instructions that set the flags previously." It's not an entire quite, but it's pretty close to that.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info! But why not set it directly to "1" (eg. "movi $1,%eax;") instead of (add $1,%eax) or incrementing.. that was the question originally =)

Comment: That's all about CPU cycles needed for those two OPs. To my knowledge `add` uses less CPU cycles that `mov`. But then again it is very arch-dependent and questionable. Also, bear in mind that assemblers choice of how to encode a higher-level language instruction is very dependent on the surrounding instructions.

Answer (score 0):

It's just important that whatever operation is used, that it is atomic.  It makes most sense to me to doing a set, rather than an add, particularly if there's a test-and-set instruction or implementation.

I found [this](http://comsci.liu.edu/~jrodriguez/testandset2.html) implementation of a TestAndSet function for the x86 architecture.  Here it uses a set (`mov`) instruction but it could have also used `add` or `inc` to do this but it would require `eax` to be `0` with the `xchg` instruction being used for atomicity.  I suppose that requiring `eax` to be zero could be a con.